# starting a scrolldiv from certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with height 400px, which contains 24 inner divs which denotes each hour of day and starts from midnight 12am and this div is at the bottom of the web page after all data is displayed. Now the problem is i wanna first display 8 am and then the user can scroll according to his/ her convenience. i m using jquery library for my project. thanks in advance.

the code like :

```
<div class="scrollingdiv">
<table>
<tr>
<td> 
<div>1</div> <div>2</div> <div>3</div> <div>4</div> <div>5</div> ...                <div>24</div> </td> 
<td> <div>1 info</div> <div>2 info</div> <div>3 info</div> <div>4 info</div>           <div>5 info</div> ... <div>24 info</div> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#yourDIVid").focus()
```

or you can use [.ScrollTo()](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

hope it helps

Comment: Cool, worked.. thanks a lot. i spent 1 day + today i was googling but didnt find anything useful... thanks alot..worked :)

Comment: Yes, scrollTo worked for me
$(".scrollingDiv").scrollTo( $('#gotoeightam'), 800 );
and that worked, thanks